# ssh bad file number when connection to raspberry pi

Tags: linux, ssh

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu(Wheezy) on my raspberry pi and I am now trying to SSH into it from my windows desktop via SSH in git bash. When I try it tells me:

```
>ssh 192.168.0.105
connect to host 192.168.0.105 port 22: Bad file number
```

When I try port 443:

```
>ssh -v 192.168.0.105 -p 443
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.105 [192.168.0.105] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.105 port 443: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.105 port 443: Bad file number
```

I found a few posts on how to fix this when people had problems connection to github etc, but no solutions for just a local network. I checked the router and cannot find anything that is blocking port 22. I also disabled the firewall on my windows pc while testing. If someone could explain why Im having this problem, and possibly how to fix it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you try to connect to 443?

Comment: When I was reading some of the solutions for git issues similar to mine that was often the first thing they tried

Comment: The next step, IMO, is to connect a keyboard and monitor to the PI and log in.  Check/stop iptables, like @Rilcon42 suggests, make sure `sshd` is running, check the logs, and (if necessary) start `sshd` non-daemonized in debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my pi was connected to a guest network rather then the main network, and the guest network apparently blocked all ssh ports.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that SSH is not enabled on the Pi.  This is the case with the Raspbian after November 2016.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh

> As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled by default. You will have to enable it manually.

To enable SSH for headless machines:

> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named `ssh`, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card.